# Automatic upload to Google Drive of new files on USB upon inserting

Tags: usb, pi-5

first post here and been getting to know my RPi over the last week.

I record band practice every week on a USB, and every time when I get home I:
A.) create a new folder for the month, named “MM MMM” on a Google Drive, if it doesn’t exist yet.
B.) create a new folder for the day, named “YYMMDD” on a Google Drive, if it doesn’t exist yet.
C.) upload the files there.

It would be great if I could write a program where this is all automated whenever I insert said USB into my RPi.

I’ve seen rclone functionalities, but that doesn’t seem to provide in:
A.) Creating new folders.
B.) Automatically running upon inserting USB.

So does anyone have some clues how I can make a program like this run upon insert of USB? And to make new folders with various names based on dates?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Get rid of the extraneous waffle in your post - we don't need to know about your band. Concentrate on writing a program that does ONE thing at a time before you even think about automating it.

Comment: See [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how this site works
and [How do I ask a good question?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: you are using a linux computer... do some research in the linux realm